# Localhost not working with Docker+Wordpress in MacOS

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm not able to run my WP environment with Docker in localhost:8000

I do this process in my `docker-compose.yml`

```
  1 version: '2'
  2
  3 services:
  4
  5   wordpress:
  6     depends_on:
  7       - mysql
  8     image: wordpress:php7.0-fpm
  9     ports:
 10       - "127.0.0.1:8000:80"
 11     volumes:
 12       - /Users/snow/Desktop/docker/htdocs/assets:/var/www/html/wp-content
 13     links:
 14       - mysql
 15     environment:
 16       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
 17       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wp
 18
 19   mysql:
 20     image: mariadb:10.1.18
 21     ports:
 22         - "127.0.0.1:8081:3306"
 23     volumes:
 24         - /Users/snow/Desktop/docker/databases:/var/lib/mysql
 25     environment:
 26         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wp
```

and every time I go to my browser. I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Logs aren't showing anything odd :/

I was thinking of my macos configuration maybe. But when I initiate a simple docker-nginx I can run it well with localhost.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: localhost is wrong, it would be the VM, not your host. You need to expose it to the default 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- check inside the wordpress container by `docker exec -ti <container_name> bash`) if it's really the web content you want, and you can list / cat the files (within the container (/var/www/html/wp-content))
- check inside the mysql container if the database files are really there, and you can connect to the database manually
- try to use a more complicated mysql password (aX35,53EeeK or something like that). MySQL has a built-in mechanism to reject it, but in this case, maybe it can't print an error because the wrapper scripts.